# how to change GWT TEXTBOX Border color

Tags: css, gwt

how can i change the default border color of GWT TextBox.
i tried this

```
.gwt-TextBox:focus {  
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

but with no luck

the default golden color remain there ,and my red color also added , but i need to replace that default golden color with red color

any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: In what file did you add the following line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is bydefault color given in the gwt jar. So you can do it intwo way.
1. Either you apply stylesheet which will override all the styles applied by you
2. You can make change in jar. (Not prefferable till you dont have any choice) Find the style applied to it from firebug and make change in gwt jar.. most probably it will be standard.css

Answer (score 5):

```
**Dependent styles**
```

Dependent style names are dependent upon the primary style name. When you add a dependent style name to a widget, GWT will prefix the new style name with the widget's primary style name, separated with a dash ('-'). You can add or remove dependent styles with the `addStyleDependentName(String)` and `removeStyleDependentName(String)` methods.

To see how this works we'll walk through a simple example. Let's say you have a `TextBox` widget. If we haven't called `setStylePrimaryName(String)` to change it, the primary style name is `gwt-TextBox`. Now suppose we want to show that the input in the text box is invalid, using the same indicator as before (red border). If we use the following code:

```
someTextBox.addStyleDependentName("invalidEntry");

then both of the CSS style rules below will be applied:

$PP_OFF
.gwt-TextBox {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.gwt-TextBox-invalidEntry {
  border-color: red; } 
}
```

When we called `someTextBox.addStyleDependentName("invalidEntry")`, GWT combined the primary style name `gwt-TextBox` with the dependent style name invalidEntry to create the final style name `gwt-TextBox-invalidEntry`.

Dependent styles are powerful because they are automatically updated whenever the primary style name changes. Continuing with our example above, if you were to change the primary style name of your text box with this call:

```
someTextBox.setStylePrimaryName("myTexBox");
```